# Adjusting sd for an ARMA(1,1) simulation given phi and theta

Tags: time-series, arima, standard-deviation, simulation

I'd like to generate model an ARMA(1,1) process with a mean of zero and a standard deviation of sigma where I specify the ARMA parameters phi and theta. How can I adjust the value of sigma in the draw from a gaussian dist'n so that the output has the correct standard deviation? In an AR(1) model the adjustment to the sd parameter would be:

```
# desired AR1 coef
phi <- 0.7
# desired sigma in y
sigma <- 0.5
# adjust sigma to account for phi
sigmaAdjusted <- sqrt(sigma^2*(1-phi^2))
n <- 500
y <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = phi),n = n, sd=sigmaAdjusted)
```

How can I adjust the sd param in model with a MA1 term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is IID Gaussian white noise with variance $\sigma^2$. Then
$$\text{Var}(y_t) = \sigma^2\left[ 1 + \frac{(\phi + \theta)^2}{1-\phi^2}\right].$$
So the adjustment is

```r
k <- 1 + (phi + theta)^2/(1-phi^2)
sigmaAdjusted <- sqrt(sigma^2 / k)
y <- arima.sim(model = list(ar = phi, ma = theta), n = n, sd = sigmaAdjusted)
```

Answer (score 3):

Letting $\sigma^2$ denote the error variance and $\sigma_Y^2$ denote the time-series variance, the $\text{ARMA}(1,1)$ model induces the relationship:

$$\begin{align}
\quad \quad \sigma_Y^2
&= \sigma^2 \bigg[ 1+\frac{(\phi+\theta)^2}{1-\phi^2} \bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 \cdot \frac{(1-\phi^2) + (\phi+\theta)^2}{1-\phi^2} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 \cdot \frac{(1-\phi^2) + (\phi^2 + 2 \phi \theta + \theta^2)}{1-\phi^2} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma^2 \cdot \frac{1 + 2 \phi \theta + \theta^2}{1-\phi^2}, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which then gives the required error variance:

$$\sigma^2 = \sigma_Y^2 \cdot \frac{1-\phi^2}{1 + 2 \phi \theta + \theta^2}. \quad \quad \quad \ $$

This is the formula you need for the error variance required to induce a particular variance for the time-series.  You can then simulate and compute probability functions for Gaussian ARMA models using the various probability functions for the `GARMA` (Gaussian ARMA) distribution in the `ts.extend` package (details and usage for this package explained in [O'Neill 2021](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2109/2109.12416.pdf)).

```
#Set model parameters
AR    <- 0.7
MA    <- 0.2
VAR_Y <- 0.5

#Compute the required error variance
ERRORVAR <- VAR_Y*(1-AR[1]^2)/(1+2*AR[1]*MA[1]+MA[1]^2)

#Generate n = 12 time-series from Gaussian ARMA(1,1) model
#Each generated time-series has m = 12 values
set.seed(1)
SIMULATION <- ts.extend::rGARMA(n = 12, m = 30, ar = AR, ma = MA,
                                mean = 0, errorvar = ERRORVAR)

#Plot the simulated time-series
plot(SIMULATION)
```

[image]